# Error on sending an Array to an ASMX WebService

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services

I wrote a webservice to create a new invoice in the database, but I am having problems to pass the line itens from a windows client to this WS.
MY WS is:

```
namespace InvoicesTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Invoices 
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Invoices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct InvoiceItem
    {
        public string Product {get; set;}

        public string PartNumber {get; set;}
    }


   [WebMethod(Description = "Create Document Type")]
   public string newDocType(string docTypeName, List<InvoiceItem> lstInvoiceItem)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < lstInvoiceItem.Count; i++)
      {
         ...
         return "ok";
      }
   }
}
```

Until here is ok. My problem is to pass the values from a windows form to this WS.
First I got an error that I should send an array instead List...

Now, I am getting an error like System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvoiceItem[] dt = new InvoiceItem[listView1.Items.Count];
    int j = 0;
    foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView1.Items)
    {
        dt[j].Product = listItem.SubItems[0].Text;
        dt[j].PartNumber = listItem.SubItems[1].Text;
        j++;
    }
    textBox1.Text = InvoicesTest.newDocType("teste", dt.ToArray());
}
```

Even working with `List<>`, it doesnt work.
I appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Richard, let me try show the result of my test to pass a custom collection as a parameter to the webservice.

**Create a custom collection class...**

```
public class Invoice
{
public int InvoiceNumber;
public string Product, PartNumber;
public Invoice() { }

public Invoice(string product, string pNumber, int iNumber)
    {
    InvoiceNumber = iNumber;
    Product = product;
    PartNumber = pNumber;
    }
}
```

**Create a Web Method...**

```
[WebMethod]
public void Method(Invoice[] fields, bool attachmentincluded)
{
       System.Collections.Generic.List<Invoice> invoices = new List<Invoice>(fields);
        foreach (Invoice i in invoices)
        {
            string N,P;
            int I;
            N =i.PartNumber;
            P = i.Product;
            I = i.InvoiceNumber;
        }
 }
```

**In the consumer application...**

```
 //Create Invoices...
        List<Invoice> lst = new List<Invoice>();

        try
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView1.Items)
            {
                Invoice aux = new Invoice();                    
                aux.Product = listItem.SubItems[0].Text;
                aux.PArtNumber = listItem.SubItems[1].Text;
                lst.Add(aux);
            }                
            textBox1.Text += localhost.Invoice(lst.ToArray(), true);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ex.ToString();
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Hi @omalukinho - if you have more information to post regarding your original question, try to edit and rephrase it. What you've posted here isn't an answer and so will likely be removed.

Comment: Kirk, I was having problem to pass the array (List) from client to the webservice. 
I got what I was looking for with the code I posted here... the connection to database is this case is not necessary (I guess)...

Comment: If this fixes your problem then it is an answer - you can mark it as the answer. I don't know the answer to your problem, I'm just trying to help you with using the site :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be better to have a list within the invoices class and populate that; e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public struct InvoiceItem
{
    public string Product {get; set;}

    public string PartNumber {get; set;}

}

public class Invoices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    /*[DataMember] ** needed If working with data contracts */
    public List<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems {get; set;}
}
```

then load it by :

```
invoice.InvoiceItems.Clear();
foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView1.Items)
    invoice.InvoiceItems.Add(new InvoiceItem() 
                           { ProductNumber = listItem.SubItems[0].Text, 
                             PartNumber = listItem.SubItems[1].Text}
                        );
```

Generally I find it way easier to work with the built in collections such as *List* rather than arrays that are somehow old fashioned and clunky to use. maybe that's just me though.